# Sunspot Rails Can't Load on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, solr

I'm not sure what changed, but solr will not start on my machine. I get the following error...

```
❯ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
2017-04-06 08:47:48.624:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2017-04-06 08:47:48.646:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /Users/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@mbcapp/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/solr/contexts at interval 0
2017-04-06 08:47:48.654:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /Users/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@mbcapp/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/solr/contexts/solr.xml
2017-04-06 08:47:48.723:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/Users/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@mbcapp/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/solr/webapps/solr.war!/ to /private/var/folders/cv/259q741957qc1v7qnf5v4kfm0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-443-
solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp
2017-04-06 08:47:49.653:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
2017-04-06 08:47:49.679:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/private/var/folders/cv/259q741957qc1v7qnf5v4kfm0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-443-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp/},/Users/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@mbcapp/ge
ms/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/solr/webapps/solr.war
2017-04-06 08:47:49.680:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/private/var/folders/cv/259q741957qc1v7qnf5v4kfm0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-443-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp/},/Users/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@mbcapp/ge
ms/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/solr/webapps/solr.war
2017-04-06 08:48:06.041:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:443: java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
2017-04-06 08:48:06.043:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5d7148e2: java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
        ... 7 more

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
```

I can use brew and install solr and get it to run and access an admin page like http://localhost:8981/solr/#/~logging, but I can't get my rails app and cucumber in particular to use that `brew install` version. Nor can I get the `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run` command to work, which works for everyone else on the team.

**EDIT:**

sunspot.yml

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    min_memory: 512M
    max_memory: 1G
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="default"     instanceDir="." dataDir="default/data"/>
    <core name="development" instanceDir="." dataDir="development/data"/>
    <core name="test"        instanceDir="." dataDir="test/data"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/sunspot.yml`?

Comment: @rposborne added it!

Comment: Can you post your solr.xml from the `solr` directory?

We need to figure out where port 443 came from, what other steps have you taken to attempt configure solr? Any ENV vars, or other configuration?

Comment: @rposborne  I've posted solo.xml. I've tried to use the brew installed version and change the path in sunspot solr yml to point to the brew installed version. I checked for ENV vars and didn't find anything. No other configuration that I can think of.

Comment: @NoahClark thanks for the bounty. I hope my answer helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to give permissions for `/solr` directory

```
chown -R $USER /solr
```

Explanation:

- `Permission denied (Bind failed)` is typical error which raises when an application doesn't have enough permissions to run.
- `/solr` directory has permissions only for `root` user (in most cases for sure)
- Current user is `/Users/noahc` which is not `root` user

Thus I understand that the current user doesn't have enough permission to run the application.

Comment: How'd you know to do this?

Comment: This is fine... but I'd rather see a more complete answer.

Comment: @NoahClark `Permission denied` is a typical Unix error. Which all new Unix users face :)

Comment: @itsnikolay  Bind failed, normally implies that unix was unable to open a to a port at the OS level,  as SOLR was requesting a port below 1000 (a privileged port)  what was the actual tell that this was an issue with the ownership of solr's own files?

Comment: @rposborne You had the same thought as mine. I thought it was a config issue with it trying to open port 443 and not the correct one which is 8981

Comment: @rposborne everything in Unix is file, so there's many issues based on files.

Answer (score 4):

1. Verify you are running the solr folder that you expect by setting an absolute path for your `SOLR_HOME=/Users/rposborne/code/my-project/solr/conf` **your path my be different**  (this is how I tell my brew install to run in the source controlled solr config in my project)
2. Verify that you do not have any `JETTY_ARGS` if you do this could be setting the port to 443 and causing the permission errors.
3. Update your `solr.xml`.  The posted xml config appears dated. Make sure you are using a solr config for your version of solr. https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/solr.xml

Perspective

It looks like the `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run` is trying to run on port 443, which is a protected port, hence the "permission denied".  You should verify the port that is set in your `config/sunspot.yml` is set to the port that you are expecting maybe `8981`.

Personally, I don't use the helper provided by sunspot as it adds a layer of abstraction that I'll eventually have to deal with in production.

To point sunspot at other installs you can configure it in a handful of different ways.

1. ENV variables:  Set the environment variable SOLR_URL which sunspot will take consider first. `SOLR_URL=http://localhost:8981/solr/your-collection-name/`
2. `config/sunspot.yml` which is modeled after `config/database.yml`

Comment: @noahclark Added some additional steps to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the extended info!